# "Could not authenticate with username and password" when trying to connect with SFTP

Tags: php, sftp

I am trying to establish connection using sftp class

my code:

```
$host = 'some ip address';
$username = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

$sftp = new SFTPConnection($host, 22);
$sftp->login($username, $pass);
```

When i run this script i get message `Could not authenticate with username  and password`

When i use same user and pass in `fileZilla` with sftp, then is ok, I can establish connection, but with script i cant

Anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: [link for help](http://www.webvamp.co.uk/blog/coding/using-php-to-connect-to-sftp/)

Comment: To check to see if OpenSSL is installed you can view all modules installed with either the ‘phpinfo()‘ function or ‘php -m‘ from the command line.

Comment: Where did you get the `SFTPConnection`?

Comment: @Malik Asif Comsats Yes it is Enabled and version is this OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips

Comment: @Martin Prikryl i am using sftp class, if you ask me that?

Comment: AFAIK, no `SFTPConnection` class is part of core PHP or PECL. So where did you get the class from?

Comment: You should follow the link in first comment. It will help. I am searching on it too. :-)

Comment: I guess he got the sftp class from [GITHUB](https://github.com/a-barzanti/nanophp/blob/master/plugins/SFTP/lib/SFTP.php) @MartinPrikryl

Comment: @MalikAsifComsats Thanks. I can guess that too. But we are not here to guess. The OP should tell us.

Comment: @Malik Asif Comsats i checked your link, but it didnt help...

Comment: @Martin Prikryl i remove @ from `ssh2_auth_password` and enabling verbose error. I get this message: `Warning: ssh2_auth_password() [function.ssh2-auth-password]: Authentication failed for user using password in includes/sftp.php on line 17`

Comment: OK, did you check server's log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here what was the problem...

My IP address wasnt been allowed on FTP server?! Now when they put my IP on whitelist, everything working just fine.

Thank you guys for your effort.

Comment: That is nice. Good luck @gandrap

Comment: Accept your answer, if it solved your problem @gandrap

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code in your sftp.php in `login(){}` function. Then tell what error does it give:

```
if (!extension_loaded('ssh2'))
{
    throw new Exception("Extension ssh2 has to be loaded to use this class. Please enable in php.ini.");
}
if (! @ssh2_auth_password($this->connection, $username, $password))
    throw new Exception("Could not authenticate with username $username " . "and password $password.");
$this->sftp = @ssh2_sftp($this->connection);
if (! $this->sftp)
    throw new Exception("Could not initialize SFTP subsystem.");
```

Edit your code to do the following[ as some people say that we should authenticate both via username_password and as well as hostKeyAuthentication ]

-------------------------------
The above description shows that:

The issue lies in the php extension assuming that you’re going to authenticate either with a password or with a public key. Because of that assumption, authenticating with a password will give you a failure and could throw you off into the wrong direction (brief description is in the link: [Must Read](https://boticca.com/blog/connecting-to-a-ssh-server-with-2-step-authentication-via-php/)).

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($host, $port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password);
if (ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($connection, $username, $pubkey, $privatekey)) {
    echo "Public Key Authentication Successful";
}
else {
    echo 'Public Key Authentication Failed' ;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: If now the Exeception is: **Extension ssh2 has to be loaded to use this class. Please enable in php.ini.** Then it means that you have to configure the **php.ini** to load ssh2 properly. Sorry to be late. @gandrap

Comment: here is the message: `Could not authenticate with username username and password password`. So i am guessing that ssh2 is loaded proprerly.

Comment: Answer updated. Please try this one and read the link provided at the end to get more clear understanding. @gandrap